# How prove this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}\le\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{xy}}}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y>0$ and $xy\le 1$. Show that
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}\le\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{xy}}}.$$

This inequality have same  follow methods?

I saw this.

Let $x,y>0, xy\le 1$. 
$$\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{1+y}\le\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{xy}},$$
because we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{1+y}-\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{xy}}&=\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{xy}}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{1+y}-\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{xy}}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2(\sqrt{xy}-1)}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+\sqrt{xy})}\le 0
\end{align}

Thank you everyone, or have other nice methods?

Comment: there is considerable difference between the two versions of the question.Did you really mean it?

Comment: Please do not use `\dfrac` in question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you show
$$\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}\le\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{xy}},$$
it follows that
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}})^2\le 2 (\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y})\le \frac{4}{1+\sqrt{xy}}.$$

Comment: It's very nice.Thank you